# Deleting an Orphaned Info-path Item in browser based infoPath form Library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, delete, orphan

We have an orphaned info path item in form library. There is no record of that item when we open in the explorer view. While trying to delete it using power shell, an error is occurred saying - access denied.Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you see the file in explorer view if you enable showing of hidden and system files?

Comment: No Arsalan, i am not able to view the file in the explorer view